# Hi i have to create a file that is named exaclty like this "\?$*'ChouMi'*$?\" in bash

Tags: bash, filenames

I tried everything i found to achieve this but everytime the '' around ChouMi are not displayed with the ls | cat -e command how can I do it please ?

[Here what it is expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAHmn.png)

Comment: You posted in the titlte `“\?$*'ChouMi'*$?\”` yet your first sentence talks about `''` (two single quotes). Note that `“` ([U+201C](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm)) is not `"` ([+0022](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0022/index.htm)). Is this a copy paste error? What should  the _exact_ name of the file be? Should it be `“\?$*'ChouMi'*$?\”`or `"\?$*'ChouMi'*$?\"` or `''\?$*'ChouMi'*$?\''`?

Comment: Please do not post links to images of text. Please post the text as text in the question.

Answer (score 1):

> Hi i have to create a file that is named exaclty like this `“\?$*'ChouMi'*$?\”` in bash

Just quote the string properly. There a cool trick to it. Open a file and output the text you want to quote:

```
“\?$*'ChouMi'*$?\”
```

save the file and do:

```
$ xargs -d'\n' printf "%q\n" < your_file
'''“\?$*'\''ChouMi'\''*$?\”'
```

The `xargs -d '\n'` read lines from `/tmp/file` and appends them as command line options to `printf`. `< your_file` redirects the content of the file to `xargs` so it can read from it. Then `printf %q\n` prints quote-quoted output of the arguments. Now you can copy whatever the text is and pass it to a command to create a file:

```
$ touch '''“\?$*'\''ChouMi'\''*$?\”'
$ ls
'“\?$*'\''ChouMi'\''*$?\”'
```